# Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Temp\HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate3Logger.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '

Tags: c#, iis-7, nhprof

We have a Website and two services hosted in `IIS7` as UAT/STG and LIVE
Since updating NHProf the staging site and UAT sites have died with the following error.

```
net4exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Temp\HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate3Logger.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String compilerVersion)
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName)
net35exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Temp\HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate3Logger.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String compilerVersion)
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: net4exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Temp\HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate3Logger.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String compilerVersion)
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName)
net35exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Temp\HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate3Logger.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String compilerVersion)
  at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName)
```

In the temp folder there are some `dll's` but they're all named randomly... bar the NHProf lib.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create manifest file (app.manifest) and change `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` to `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`. Now should be ok.

Maniest code example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!-- <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->

</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Man thats gross :D
Removed it for now will add as needed.